# Redux combineReducers Uncaught Type error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs, redux

I beginer to react and redux and I have used **combineReducers** and getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Without the combineReducer it is working fine. Below is snippet of my Reducers.

**reducers\article.js:**

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../actiontypes/action-types";

const initialState = {
articles: []
};

const articleReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

switch (action.type){
case ADD_ARTICLE:
return {...state, articles: [...state.articles, action.payload] };
default:
return state;
}
};

export default articleReducer;
```

**reducers\index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import articleReducer from "./article";

export default combineReducers({
articles : articleReducer
});
```

**actions\index.js**

```
import {ADD_ARTICLE} from "../actiontypes/action-types";

export const addArticle = article => ({type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload: article});
```

**store/index.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const initialArticlesState = {
    articles: [{"title":"some title", "id":"04503"}]
};

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialArticlesState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()  
    )

);

export default store;
```

**components\form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import uuidv1 from "uuid";
import { addArticle } from "../js/actions/index";

class ConnectedForm extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: ""
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        const { title } = this.state;
        const id = uuidv1();
        console.log("submit",{ title, id });
        this.props.addArticle();
        this.setState({ title: "" });
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        const { title } = this.state;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="title"
                    value={title}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                SAVE
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addArticle: article => dispatch(addArticle(article))
    };
};

const Form = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedForm);

export default Form;
```

Comment: You have some weird characters like `“`, `‘` or three dots. Is there a copy/past issue?

Comment: Those were three dots (...) spread operator, I think while pasting it here it got changed. I have edited the post.

Comment: I know that they are spread operators but not the standard ones :) Creating store works for me without issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/5zk94ylnxn Of course I haven't tried an action but store side is ok. How is you action crettor and how do you apply it? If possible please post your whole code.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are creating your store?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: @devserkan I have created forked your sandbox and updated my code there.. https://codesandbox.io/embed/r75j02zvko

Comment: Sorry, i deleted the sandbox. Just try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your initialArticleState like this:

```
const initialArticlesState = [
    { title: "some title", id: "04503" },
];
```

Probably you want the state as an array of objects. Those objects are articles right? So, when you set up you initial state like that you are exposing an articles state thanks to combineReducers. Your top redux state now includes an articles array which has article objects.

Then, change your reducer return statement like that:

```
return [ ...state, action.payload ];
```

Now, if you want some other things other than articles in your articles state, you can change your state shape of course. For example:

```
const initialArticlesState = {
    articles: [
        { title: "some title", id: "04503" },
    ],
    totalArticleNumber: 1,
};
```

If you do so, then you will have an articles state, which includes articles and totalArticleNumber. In this case maybe you want to change the state name maybe.

Reducer would be something like that:

```
return { ...state, articles: [ ...state.articles, action.payload ] };
```

Comment: Got it working after above modifications to the state shape but getting a warning message: The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of "Array". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "articles".

Comment: How did you change exactly? I've created another codebox now, working nice: https://codesandbox.io/s/v8vwm21vol I've cleaned your code a little bit.

Comment: Yea, its working fine now, I was passing incorrect argument to mapStateToProps in another component. Appreciate you help.